# Is it possible to create a text list of all my apps on the (Mac) App Store?

Tags: mac-appstore, text

Since I can't copy the list of my 'Purchased' Apps on Apple's App Store, I'm wondering if there's any other way to do this. I have little computer savvy, so if there's a solution it'd have to be step-by-step. Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

These are great answers but I'll mention the `mas` command line tool here too because it's a single command for what you want (once you install it) and quite often Apple's App Store app simply doesn't work, and `mas` always works.

Download the app here https://github.com/mas-cli/mas/releases (select `mas-cli.zip`).  Developers can use `brew install mas` which is easier ...

Open a Terminal in the same folder where you unzip it, then type "./mas list".

You probably have to do "./mas signin" first, I can't remember the workflow.

Comment: Hi and thanks for the response. I tried this to no avail. I imagine this is likely due to my inexperience, rather than your solution. I unzipped **mas-cli.zip** in my Utilities Folder in Applications + then removed **mas-cli.zip** from the folder, leaving **mas** behind (in the same folder as the **Terminal** Application). I then typed **./mas list** and got
**-bash: ./mas: No such file or directory**. When I typed **./mas signin** it said **-bash: ./mas: No such file or directory**

Comment: Yeah it sounds like your Terminal prompt is in a different folder from the `mas` binary.  Your can find which folder your Terminal is in by typing `pwd` (present working directory) then navigate to the correct directory using `cd` (change directory).

Comment: Ah! That was it. After typing pwd, I realized where **mas** needed to be, and installed it there. I then typed **./mas list** in the Terminal window and a list appeared. Unfortunately, it too, does not include uninstalled App Store apps, so I am still searching for a solution which works with Sierra.   p.s. as per your instructions in the comments above, after trying **pwd** I then typed **cd**, but as I didn't understand the result (which to my inexperienced eyes, appeared to be nothing) I carried on as I've described. Is it necessary for me to **"undo"** the cd 'command' (and if so, how? Tx)

Comment: This probably isn't the place for a command line tutorial but here's a link to get you started https://www.davidbaumgold.com/tutorials/command-line/

Comment: Tx That IS an excellent tutorial (although I also had to look up the definition of a Directory! :) anyway...I am no longer worried.

Answer (score 16):

In systems up to 10.11.6 you can save the "Purchased" page as html file to disk:

- Quit App Store.app
- Open Terminal.app in /Applications/Utilities
- Enter `defaults write com.apple.appstore ShowDebugMenu -bool true` and hit the <kbd>Return/⏎</kbd> key to show the debug menu in App Store.app.
- Open App Store.app (check that the "Debug" menu is available!)

  [image]

  If you have some hidden purchases and want them to be listed also, unhide them in your account.
- Open the "Purchased" page - log in with your Apple ID if required.
- Hit <kbd>cmd</kbd><kbd>U</kbd>
- Quit App Store.app
- Bring Terminal.app to the front and enter:

  ```
  cp ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.appstore/Data/Library/Documentation/pageSource.html ~/Desktop/pageSource.html
  ```

  and hit the <kbd>Return/⏎</kbd> key. The pageSource.html file is now on your desktop and can be opened with a browser
- (Enter `defaults write com.apple.appstore ShowDebugMenu -bool false` and hit the <kbd>Return/⏎</kbd> key to remove the debug menu in App Store.app again.)
- Enter `exit` and hit the <kbd>Return/⏎</kbd> key.
- Quit Terminal.app

Comment: Nice answer! :) Do you happen to know either way what the story is with this solution on macOS Sierra?

Comment: @Monomeeth You probably know that the debug menu doesn't exist anymore in Sierra's App Store.app. I tried to dive into the various cache/database files in ~/Library/Containers/com.apple.appstore/Data but haven't been able to find anything useful until now...

Comment: D'Oh, I'd forgotten about the removal of the Debug menu. As an aside, I've just tested PeterVP's answer on both El Capitan and Sierra and that works nicely too. It's quick and produces nothing but a text file.

Comment: Unfortunately I updated fm Yosemite to Sierra a month ago (only because the iPod to Photos transfer was giving me problems). I wish I hadn't, not only because I keep getting the 'spinning ball', but because this beautifully clear solution may have been what I was looking for, as the list is created from the App Store, rather than my computer. Thx!

Answer (score 10):

Both Klanomath and PeterVP provide suitable answers. If all you want is a list of the apps, I'd refer you to those. However, if you'd like other details included (such as Version etc) or you just don't like using Terminal, you can achieve what you want with these steps:

1. Go to **Apple > About This Mac**
2. Click on the <kbd>System Report...</kbd> button on the window that appears
3. In the lefthand pane you'll see a list of headings and subheadings
4. Expand the *Software* heading
5. Select the *Applications* subheading
6. After a while you should see a list of all Apps appear on the righthand side
7. Now click on the *Obtained From* column heading (this will sort your apps)
8. Scroll down till you see all the apps labelled as obtained from Mac App Store
9. Click on the first app from the Mac App Store and then press and hold the <kbd>shift</kbd> key down while you also select the last app from the Mac App Store
10. As you do this, the bottom half of the righthand side window populates with details of each of your selected apps
11. Once you've selected the apps, click on the bottom half and use the <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>A</kbd> shortcut to select all
12. Now copy (or <kbd>command</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>) your selected items
13. Now you can paste these into TextEdit or your text editor of choice

I know this is a little messy, and it probably gives you a lot more detail than you wanted, so hopefully someone comes up with a better solution. But in the meantime it may get you where you wanted to be.

Comment: Another example of how to write an answer for a novice! Thank-you for this extremely NON-messy answer. I am saving it too, for occasions when I DO want more info, but as I commented to PeterVP, I was hoping for a list of all purchases from the App Store, as I haven't downloaded them all.

Answer (score 8):

I use a shell script, in Terminal enter:

```
find /Applications -path '*Contents/_MASReceipt/receipt' -maxdepth 4 -print |\sed 's#.app/Contents/_MASReceipt/receipt#.app#g; s#/Applications/##'
```

This will list all applications you bought on the Mac App Store.

If you redirect the result to a text file like so:

```
find /Applications -path '*Contents/_MASReceipt/receipt' -maxdepth 4 -print |\sed 's#.app/Contents/_MASReceipt/receipt#.app#g; s#/Applications/##' > ~/Desktop/PurchasedApps.txt
```

you will create a plain text file on your desktop named *PurchasedApps.txt*.

This will list all applications **downloaded** from the App Store, bought and free. It will **not** show applications you once downloaded, but have since deleted from your Mac.

Comment: Nice answer! And it works on Sierra as well. :)

Comment: Thank-you for this answer, which I found easy to implement, but I'd prefer a solution that included ALL my Apps on the App Store (some of which I never have installed).

Answer (score 4):

Create a new Smart Search. See this Macworld article for help

http://www.macworld.com/article/3165624/os-x/how-to-create-spotlight-searches-to-store-as-smart-folders-in-macos-sierra.html

[image: Smart Search for App Store purchases]

kMDItemAppStoreHasReceipt != 1

Comment: not ignoring your possible solution - but it IS a long article :)

Comment: The article is there for anyone that wants more detail. The screenshot is all you really need. I added the text for the Raw Query to make it easy to paste into the search.